# Django: When to use QuerySet none()

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Just came across this in the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#none)

> Calling none() will create a queryset that never returns any objects
>   and no query will be executed when accessing the results. A qs.none()
>   queryset is an instance of EmptyQuerySet.

I build a lot of CRUD apps (surprise) and I can't think of a situation where I would need to use `none()`.

Why would one want to return an EmptyQuerySet?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Usually in instances where you need to provide a `QuerySet`, but there isn't one to provide - such as calling a method or to give to a template.

The advantage is if you *know* there is going to be no result (or don't want a result) and you still *need* one, `none()` will not hit the database.

For a non-realistic example, say you have an API where you can query your permissions. If the account hasn't been confirmed, since you already have the `Account` object and you can see that `account.is_activated` is `False`, you could skip checking the database for permissions by just using `Permission.objects.none()`

Comment: I believe this is correct, but I will throw in that it seems like the some of the core developers are in support of removing the None() method.  Please see ticket django support ticket 19184 https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19184

Comment: The reasons given there are all valid, but they are a criticism of the implementation, not the pattern.

Comment: I would not disagree with you...  just adding an observation about the current feature.

Answer (score 22):

In cases where you want to append to querysets but want an empty one to begin with
Similar to conditions where we instantiate an empty list to begin with but gradually keep appending meaningful values to it
example..

```
def get_me_queryset(conditionA, conditionB, conditionC):
    queryset = Model.objects.none()

    if conditionA:
        queryset |= some_complex_computation(conditionA)
    elif conditionB:
        queryset |= some_complex_computation(conditionB)

    if conditionC:
        queryset |= some_simple_computation(conditionC)

    return queryset
```

`get_me_queryset` should almost always return instance of `django.db.models.query.QuerySet` (because good programming) and not `None` or `[]`, or else it will introduce headaches later..

This way even if none of the conditions come `True`, your code will still remain intact. No more type checking

For those who do not undestand `|` operator's usage here:

```
queryset |= queryset2
```

It translates to:

```
queryset = queryset + queryset
```

Answer (score 3):

another use of queryset.none is when you don't know if there will be objects but do not want to raise an error.

example:

```
class DummyMixin(object):

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        """ Return all the pks of objects into the context """

        context = super(DummyMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        objects_pks = context.get(
            "object_list",
            Mymodel.objects.none()
        ).values_list("pk", flat=True)

        context["objects_pks"] = objects_pks
```

Answer (score 2):

Another good use case for this is if some calling method wants to call `.values_list()` or similar on results. If the method returned None, you'd get an error like

`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values_list'`

But if your clause returns `MyModel.objects.none()` instead of `None`, the calling code will be happy, since the returned data is an empty queryset rather than a None object.

Another way of putting it is that it allows you to not mix up return types (like "this function returns a QuerySet or None," which is messy).

Answer (score 1):

It's useful to see where `qs.none()` is used in other examples in the Django docs.  For example, when [initializing a model formset using a queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#changing-the-queryset) if you want the resulting formset to be empty the example given is:

`formset = AuthorFormSet(queryset=Author.objects.none())`

Answer (score 0):

[**none()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#none) is used in [**get_queryset()**](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L2440) to return **an empty queryset** depending on the state of [**has_view_or_change_permission()**](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L595) as shown below:

```py
class BaseModelAdmin(metaclass=forms.MediaDefiningClass):

    # ...

    def has_view_or_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return self.has_view_permission(request, obj) or self.has_change_permission(
            request, obj
        )

# ...

class InlineModelAdmin(BaseModelAdmin):

    # ...

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        queryset = super().get_queryset(request)
        if not self.has_view_or_change_permission(request):
            queryset = queryset.none() # Here
        return queryset
```